# Mail sending problem from sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have configured the mail in SQL Server but when I am sending mail from SQL Server it is showing mail queue message but I am not getting the mail. I also grant the permission to `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` sp for public.

my mail sending code as follows.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='test@bba-reman.com',            
@subject = 'test',            
@body = 'Test',            
@body_format = 'HTML';
```

I just do not understand why I am not getting mail where as I am getting mail queue message when sending.

please guide me.

thanks

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click database mail (In the Management tree) and choose View Database mail log.
You can see there the errors regarding the mail sent.

Can you post the errors you see in the log ?